# Django model with dynamic parameters : how to order?

Tags: django, django-models

I want to have dynamic parameters, so I made these models :

```
class DynamicObject(models.Model):
    uuid = UUIDField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    synopsis = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class DynamicObjectParam(models.Model):
    obj = models.ForeignKey(DynamicObject,related_name='params')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=255)


To list parameters for a particular object, I do :
obj = DynamicObject.objects.get(uuid='xxx')
for p in obj.params:
    print p.name,p.value
```

To filter a particular parameter, I do (here all objects having the parameter 'server_type' with value 'Sun SF25K':

```
query_set = DynamicObject.objects.filter(params__name__exact='server_type',params__value__exact='Sun SF25K')
```

But how can I order by a specific parameter name?
For example I would like to do something equivalent to:

```
ordered_query_set = query_set.order_by(params__name='server_name')
```

Of course, this django syntax does not exist, so how can I proceed?

Comment: That's not what you're doing. You're filtering DynamicObject that has a parameter named "server_type" and a parameter valued "Sun SF25K". There is no guarantee that the conditions will both apply on the same parameter object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Found a way :

```
ordered_query_set = query_set.extra(select={'param_server_name':'SELECT value FROM app_dynamicobjectparam WHERE dynamicobjectparam.obj_id=app_dynamicobject.uuid AND ci_dynamicobjectparam.name="server_name"'}).order_by('param_server_name')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can order by params__name but you won't be able to tell the ORM 'order by this pattern of string'.

Do it in Python on the queryset or try raw SQL.